# Getting rid of punctiations in a string in python

Tags: python, indexing, palindrome, punctuation

This is a code I wrote for removing commas and full stops from a string

```
forbidden=(",",".")
text=input("Your sentence")
for i in range(0,len(text)):
    if text[i] in forbidden:
         text=text.replace(text[i],'')
         i-=1
print text
```

My input was a,n

But it gives an error saying that string index is out of range

Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Since you replace the punctuation with a null string, you shorten the length of the string, which affects  the indices.  Use `" "` (space) instead of `""` and notice that it runs.  You could then replace spaces on the final text after the `for` loop, although there are other ways to solve this.  Also,the decrementer `i-=1`can be removed since `range` is driven the indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

- `len(text)` is calculated exactly once at the beginning of the loop. The fact that `text` shrinks as you iterate over it, doesn't have any impact on what values `i` will have later on.
- decrementing `i` within your loop has no effect on the value of `i` in the next iteration. Python simply steamrolls over the old value without looking at it.

If you're absolutely committed to implementing this algorithm by iterating over the indices of `text`, then using a `while` loop would resolve both of these problems. A `while` loops' condition evaluates at every iteration, and you have full control over the value you're incrementing/decrementing.

```
forbidden=(",",".")
text=raw_input("Your sentence: ")
i = 0
while i < len(text):
    if text[i] in forbidden:
        text=text.replace(text[i],'')
    else:
        i+=1
print text
```

Output:

```
Your sentence: foo,bar,baz.qux,troz,zort.
foobarbazquxtrozzort
```

... But if you're open to a different approach, it would save you a lot of effort if you iterated over the forbidden characters instead of `text`.

```
forbidden=(",",".")
text=raw_input("Your sentence: ")
for c in forbidden:
    text = text.replace(c, "")
print text
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne!  The steamrolling over a for loop condition was new to me. It was different from other languages. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in better way using `re` module

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "asdsd,dweds.,sdfsf."
>>> re.sub('(,|\.)', '', s)
'asdsddwedssdfsf'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But can you tell me the bug in my code?

Comment: Please see @kevin's answer, it explains everything ;)

Comment: Yep. Had just noticed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a string with a simple for in loop, you don't need to bother with an index.

```
forbidden=(",",".")
text=input("Your sentence")
for c in text:
    if c in forbidden:
        text=text.replace(c,'')
print text
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked like a charm.
But, can you tell me the problem with my code?

Comment: It is your `-= i`. If you run the for loop `for i in range(0,10):` and print `i` inside you will see the first index is -1 which isn't a valid index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehensions` to filter dots and commas then use `reduce()` to add the elements into a `string` like:

```
    forbidden = (",", ".")
    text = 'a,n'
    text = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [i for i in text if i not in forbidden])
    print text
```

or you can use

```
text = ''.join([i for i in text if i not in forbidden])
```

output:

```
an
```